# How do I add spacing in the UITABLEVIEW between cells?

Tags: uitableview, spacing

Hi i am new to swift and i am looking for a way to make space between cells.

I have tried different types of code found here but neither works.

How do you make spacing between Cells in the uitableview?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto layout, you can embed your cell design inside a view and add top and bottom spacing to that view with respect to content view.

Consider below screenshot, the red coloured view contains all the design and have top and bottom spacing with content view.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check it out! Appreciate it